# extract characters from a big text file

Tags: string, grep

first question here, so be nice ... :)

i have a big text file (asdf.rep) and i need to search many numbers, i put it on a list txt file (list.txt)

my list.txt looks something like this:

```
123456
555555
888888
123456
```

then, i need to find these numbers on a big file that contain something like this:

```
number2 789789
assasaasjalsjkalksjlkaj
data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data
data data data data data data data data data data data data data data  data data data data
number key 555555

number2 789791
assasaasjalsjkalksjlkaj
data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data
data data data data data data data data data data data data data data  data data data data
number key 123456
```

i used grep -f to search from a list,

```
grep -f list.txt -B4 asdf.rep
```

this show me the number key i have and number2 5 lines above, then my question is:

there some other way to display just the number key and the "number2"?

something like

```
number key 555555 number2 789789

number key 123456 number2 789791
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using grep to select the matching lines, you can also use sed to "hack up" the lines that grep is reporting.  In UNIX, you can unite two or more commands in a "pipeline," where the output of each is submitted as the input to the next, so that each tool in the sequence can perform its own transformation task.

grep | sed (read "grep pipe sed" or "grep through sed") is a commonly encountered sequence: one often wants to (a) locate matching lines and then (b) perform some textual transformation on the lines.

I'm not sure why you're using the -B4 flag to select surrounding context.  That's not a very UNIXish thing to do.  If the lines that you break across several lines ("number2 blah blah . . . number key blah") actually correspond to SINGLE LINES of text--terminated by a newline character, '\n'--there's hardly ever a need to display surrounding context.

At the end of your grep command, add the following characters:

**| sed 's/number2 \([^ ]*\).*\(number key\)/\1 \2/'**

Dictated, the string reads **single quote s slash number2 space backslash left parenthesis left bracket circumflex space right bracket star backslash right parenthesis dot star backslash left parenthesis number space key backslash right parenthesis slash backslash one space backslash two single quote**.

That complicated string (be ULTRA-CAREFUL about the spaces and the backslashes and such) deletes everything that FOLLOWS the number (like 789791 in your example) up to, but not including, the words "number key."

Comment: I stick to the SED solution more typically than to the AWK solution because (a) AWK is unfamiliar to many readers and (b) there's an awful lot of setup and teardown associated with AWKing something.  Never mind the teardown--you've already gotten your output at that point--but there's that thorny setup.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} ($NF in a){print "number key",$NF,$1,$2}' list.txt RS="" asdf.rep
```

#### Example

Let's use these two files as input:

```
$ cat list.txt
123456
555555
888888
123456
```

And:

```
$ cat asdf.rep
number2 789789
assasaasjalsjkalksjlkaj
data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data
data data data data data data data data data data data data data data  data data data data
number key 555555

number2 789791
assasaasjalsjkalksjlkaj
data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data
data data data data data data data data data data data data data data  data data data data
number key 123456
```

Run our code:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} ($NF in a){print "number key",$NF,$1,$2}' list.txt RS="" asdf.rep
number key 555555 number2 789789
number key 123456 number2 789791
```

#### How it works

- `FNR==NR{a[$1]; next}`

  As we read throught the first file, denoted by `FNR==NR`, we add the number on each line as a key in associative array `a`.  We then skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `($NF in a){print "number key",$NF,$1,$2}`

  If we get here, we are reading the second file, `asdf.rep`.  We read this file a paragraph at a time.  If the last number in the paragraph matches any key in `a`, then we print the output.
- `list.txt RS="" asdf.rep`

  This tells awk to read the file `list.txt` first.  It is read in the default way: line-by-line.

  `RS=""` tells awk to read the next file a paragraph at a time.

  `asdf.rep` tells awk which file to read next.